# Visual Studio will not run things in browser and certain shortcuts do nothing

Tags: html, visual-studio

I'm new to JavaScript (/html in general) and to visual studio. I seem to have two different issues: I'm having trouble running code in browsers, and some of the keyboard shortcuts are broken.

I've recently installed Visual Studio 2017. Everything seems great except I need a way to test my open file. I've looked online at certain guides which tell me to configure the task runner to be able to do so. The problem is, to get to the tasks.json which I need to edit, I have to open the command palette with ctrl + shift + p, which doesn't seem to work. Additionally, I can't find any other way to open the command palette using the bar at the top nor can I find any other way to open tasks.json. Also, I noticed that I should be able to run code in browser using the "View in Browser (Google Chrome)" and "Browse With..." options under "file". The keyboard shortcut doesn't work for View in Browser, and when I click on both options, I get a dialogue box with the error "The operation could not be completed. Class not registered".

How can I set things up properly, or at least be able to properly test my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is Visual Studio Code, not Microsoft Visual Studio.
Both were similar but target different programming platform.
If you want to develop web application, HTML/CSS/ts/js etc, better if you use VS Code.